# Как вывести главную страницу django python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-cms

При создании проекта django, выводится главная страница, base.html

Я создал блог (туториал django girl),и прописал в urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Все ок. Теперь я хочу, перенести страницу блога в подпапку, localhost/blog/, что не проблема

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

но как мне обратно указать паттерн на главную страницу base.html или надо создать отдельно startapp для главной  страницы?

```
path('', TEMPLATES, {"template": "base.html"})

path('', views.home, name='home')
```

пробовал это, не работает

Answer (score 1):

Я так решил

**youapps/urls.py**

```
# добавляем 
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**youapps/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, '../templates/base.html') #здесь путь к нужному шаблону
```